# It seems that maximum experience in salary calculator is 30 years, not 20+

Tags: bug, salary-calculator

Placeholder text for experience field says that 20 is maximum and interpreted as 20 and more (i.e. 20+).

> [image: placeholder]

I did some experiments and noticed that actual limit is 30 years.

[20 years:](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary/results?l=california&ed=2&ex=20&dr%5B0%5D=DesktopDeveloper)

> [image: 20+]

[30 years:](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary/results?l=california&ed=2&ex=30&dr%5B0%5D=DesktopDeveloper)

> [image: 30]

Choosing more than 30 years doesn’t increase the salary. For instance, [10000 years of experience](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary/results?l=california&ed=2&ex=10000&dr%5B0%5D=DesktopDeveloper):

> [image: 10k]

Therefore maximum experience should be limited by 30 years, and for any biggest value tag-styled text should be “30+ years experience”.

Comment: Legends say that your last test only gives accurate results for Fortran and PHP devs.

Comment: 20+, so 21 would be the same as 30 or 1000?

Comment: Why is 10,000 even an option?  Come on, QA!

Comment: @Jacob It's for those of us with 10,000 years of experience.

Comment: @JacobG. I think it's for Jon Skeet

Comment: Those of us who are channeling the spirit of a 40,000-year-old Neanderthal shaman/programmer need to be "experienced" differently. :-)

Comment: Anything more than 30+ is confusing. UX is about not getting confused, and not loosing confidence on the system. 10000 looks like a stupid developer bug.

Comment: @Siddharth It's not really a UX problem, you can pass the site arbitrary numbers to the `ex` GET parameter ;-)